# Capturing const this

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

right now I have an object function with a lambda, in order to use member functions and variables I would have to(or of course capture all..):

```
void MyClass::MyFunc() {

    auto myLambda = [this](){...};
}
```

Is there a way to explicitly state to capture a const this ? I know I could:

```
void MyClass::MyFunc() {
    MyClass const* const_my_class = this;
    auto myLambda = [const_my_class](){...};
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: I'd be surprised if there's a better way to do this, but it would be interesting to wait and see if someone can come up with it.

Comment: It would seem so trivial that you'd need it especially when doing items like parallel_for_each..

Comment: this would be constant if your MyFunc was constant. I assume it would be since you need this to be const

Comment: Define the lambda in a `const` member function.

Comment: In C++14 you'll be able to use an expression capture to do that without a separate variable declaration.

Comment: I specifically don't want MyFunc to be const of course :)

Comment: just put the lambda's contents into a `const` member function. or if it absolutely has to be a lambda/function object you could create the lambda inside a separate `const` member function

Comment: @Joe But how will you return that lambda from a different helper function? You cannot specify a lambda type as a return type, so you're stuck with something like `std::function<T()>` for some `T`. Of course, C++14 solves that with an `auto` return type, but then, in C++14 you wouldn't need a separate function in the first place, as Ben Voigt pointed out.

Comment: @hvd true, to return it you'd need C++14 or a `std::function`. The real question in this case is, IMO, is a lambda even necessary/appropriate here?

Comment: @Alex the pointer itself will be const, but not the pointee

Comment: @BenVoigt: Why the future tense? :) [disclaimer: yeah yeah tags]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per *§5.1.2* in the standard (N3485), the definition of *lambda-capture*  is:


```
lambda-capture:
    capture-default
    capture-list
    capture-default , capture-list
capture-default:
    &
    =
capture-list:
    capture ... opt
    capture-list , capture ... opt
capture:
    identifier
    & identifier
    this
```

So, you only can have `=`, `&`, `this`, *identifier*, `&` *identifier* in the capture list. You can not have expressions, for example casting `this` to a `const`.

Some simple expressions in the capture list in higher versions (`-std=c++1y`) is avaiable, for example:

```
auto myLambda = [self = static_cast<MyClass const*>(this)](){

    // Use `self` instead of `this` which is `const`

};
```

Of course, it's not like capturing `this` that you can access members as same as local variables.